# How to write textfield label properly in Reactjs material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

Hi i am using material ui in my project. But the top border is getting inside of label "Final Volume" from the end as shown in image. How to fix this.

[image]

```js
< TextField
    fullWidth
    disabled
    id = "outlined-disabled"
    label = "Customer Name"
    value = "abc"
    variant = "outlined"
    InputProps = {
        {
            className: classes.pricingButton,
        }
    }
/>
```

Comment: try using the `key` property to the Textbox so you force it to render a new element. Something like `key="Customer Name"`

Comment: your screenshot doesn't match the code you are sharing. We will not know if there are error in your real code. And what is pricingButton class? Can u try removing it.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial in pricingButton, i have set  height: "41px",
    fontSize: "12px",..... when i remove this class it is working properly... i want to set the height of textfield too

Comment: please share all the codes. We won't know whether it's caused by fontSize or height, if you don't share them.

Comment: @PriyankDeepSingh There is no problem after remove InputProps. Please provide more info on the class pricingButton.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-mclaren-o20s5?file=/src/App.js)